# Error in style.sass after running npm run serve

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, vuejs2

I tried running npm run serve in my VueJS project but I have encountered a syntax error saying: "Expected identifier" pointing to this: "will-change: transform, opacity".
Full log of the error: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIbgg.png)

I tried installing node-sass, changed the npm and node version but it did not work. I'm current using npm 6.9.0 and node 12.0.0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`node-sass` is deprecated, try using `sass` package, which is a distribution of `Dart Sass`

```
pnpm add -D sass
```